# Optimizing postgres sorting by word_similarity

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, postgresql-12

I have a table with 2M rows of hotel names in Postgresql 12. I am building a typeahead so users can quickly find the hotel by name. I have played around with different Postgres options including FTS, trigrams, and levenshtein distance.

word_similarity in pg_trgm gives me the best results, but whenever I need to sort by the similarity score, things get too slow (without sorting the query finishes in milliseconds):

```
SELECT name, word_similarity('trade center new york mariott', name) AS sml from hotels_hotel where 'trade center new york mariott' %> name ORDER BY sml DESC LIMIT 5;

                                          name                                          |    sml
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------
 Courtyard by Marriott New York Downtown Manhattan/World Trade Center Area              | 0.53846157
 Fairfield Inn & Suites by Marriott New York Downtown Manhattan/World Trade Center Area | 0.53846157
 Residence Inn by Marriott New York Downtown Manhattan/World Trade Center Area          | 0.53846157
 AC Hotel by Marriott New York Times Square                                             |    0.53125
 Courtyard by Marriott World Trade Center, Abu Dhabi                                    |  0.5263158
(5 rows)

Time: 9602.969 ms (00:09.603)
```

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE, COSTS) SELECT name, word_similarity('trade center new york mariott', name) AS sml from hotels_hotel where 'trade center new york mariott' %> name ORDER BY sml DESC LIMIT 5;
                                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=65390.53..65391.11 rows=5 width=27) (actual time=9619.113..9625.482 rows=5 loops=1)
   Output: name, (word_similarity('trade center new york mariott'::text, (name)::text))
   Buffers: shared hit=1746167
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=65390.53..65589.11 rows=1702 width=27) (actual time=9619.109..9625.474 rows=5 loops=1)
         Output: name, (word_similarity('trade center new york mariott'::text, (name)::text))
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=1746167
         ->  Sort  (cost=64390.50..64392.63 rows=851 width=27) (actual time=9612.578..9612.580 rows=4 loops=3)
               Output: name, (word_similarity('trade center new york mariott'::text, (name)::text))
               Sort Key: (word_similarity('trade center new york mariott'::text, (hotels_hotel.name)::text)) DESC
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
               Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
               Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
               Buffers: shared hit=1746167
               Worker 0: actual time=9610.098..9610.100 rows=5 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=581861
               Worker 1: actual time=9609.314..9609.317 rows=5 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=579828
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using hotels_hotel_name_a9005e17 on public.hotels_hotel  (cost=0.43..64376.37 rows=851 width=27) (actual time=4.040..9606.166 rows=15070 loops=3)
                     Output: name, word_similarity('trade center new york mariott'::text, (name)::text)
                     Filter: ('trade center new york mariott'::text %> (hotels_hotel.name)::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 666002
                     Heap Fetches: 2
                     Buffers: shared hit=1746113
                     Worker 0: actual time=0.281..9603.591 rows=14890 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=581834
                     Worker 1: actual time=8.157..9602.811 rows=14678 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=579801
 Planning Time: 0.396 ms
 Execution Time: 9625.576 ms
(31 rows)

Time: 9626.933 ms (00:09.627)
```

**Is there any way I can optimize this query?** Happy to build a huge index as I suppose is needed.

Why word_similarity is best for my use case:

- allows typos (notice I misspell marriott in my query)
- allows different ordering of the words

---

### Edit 1

The explain analyze without sorting:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT name, word_similarity('trade center new york mariott', name) AS sml from hotels_hotel where 'trade center new york mariott' %> name LIMIT 5;
                                                      QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..1264.75 rows=5 width=27) (actual time=0.391..15.981 rows=5 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on hotels_hotel  (cost=0.00..516777.29 rows=2043 width=27) (actual time=0.384..15.969 rows=5 loops=1)
         Filter: ('trade center new york mariott'::text %> (name)::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 292
 Planning Time: 0.285 ms
 Execution Time: 16.041 ms
(6 rows)

Time: 17.800 ms
```

### Edit 2

The relevant indices present on the table:

```
CREATE INDEX autocomplete_gist ON public.hotels_hotel USING gist (name gist_trgm_ops)
CREATE INDEX autocomplete_name_idx ON public.hotels_hotel USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops)
CREATE INDEX hotels_hotel_name_a9005e17 ON public.hotels_hotel USING btree (name)
CREATE INDEX hotels_hotel_name_a9005e17_like ON public.hotels_hotel USING btree (name varchar_pattern_ops)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hotels_hotel_pkey ON public.hotels_hotel USING btree (id)
CREATE INDEX hotels_hotel_popularity_05985c85 ON public.hotels_hotel USING btree (popularity)
```

### Edit 3

The new query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT name, word_similarity('trade center new york mariott', name) AS sml from hotels_hotel ORDER BY name <->> 'trade center new york mariott' LIMIT 5;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN

 Limit  (cost=0.41..5.65 rows=5 width=31) (actual time=3632.397..3633.554 rows=5 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1 read=32537
   I/O Timings: read=184.432
   ->  Index Scan using autocomplete_gist on hotels_hotel  (cost=0.41..2140836.75 rows=2043215 width=31) (actual time=3632.394..3633.548 rows=5 loops=1)
         Order By: ((name)::text <->> 'trade center new york mariott'::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=1 read=32537
         I/O Timings: read=184.432
 Planning Time: 0.250 ms
 Execution Time: 3679.847 ms
```

Comment: now that you have added the index m maybe update the query plan for your query in your question , this time do EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)

Comment: OK, here is the json: https://gist.github.com/mikob/301f340518d372612d81a40698d41f8f

Comment: @eshirvana No JSON execution plans, please.

Comment: Your query itself is inconsistent.  `word_similarity` pairs up with `<%`, not with `%>`.  So you are filtering by one thing, but then ordering by a different thing.

Comment: @jjanes oops! I've fixed that and it's brought down the original query to 3000ms (the new query in edit 3 is still better).

Comment: Your fastest query is not IO bound, but presumably is CPU bound.  And I can't reproduce the low speed just by making up gibberish data.  To investigate further, I think you would need to make available your list of 2 million hotel names.

Comment: @jjanes Monitoring CPU, only one core spikes when I run the query. Can this query not take advantage of parallelization? max_worker_processes and max_parallel_workers are both 8. Is it possible to change the size of grams - eg 4 gram or 5 gram instead of trigram to reduce the calculation?

Comment: I saw there was improvements to GiST and sorting mentioned in the postgres 13 release notes. Tried on 13.1 but there was no performance difference.

Comment: You could always write your own extension inspired by pg_trgm but using different gram size.  But it would be a lot of work, and I see no reason to think it would do any better.  I don't think KNN can use parallelization.

Answer (score 1):

Use a GiST index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON hotels_hotel USING gist (name gist_trgm_ops);
```

and search like this:

```
SELECT name,
       word_similarity('trade center new york mariott', name) AS sml
FROM hotels_hotel
ORDER BY name <->> 'trade center new york mariott'
LIMIT 5;
```

That will get you the five closest matches.

Comment: I have a gist index (someone erased the comment showing which indexes I have) `hotels_hotel                | autocomplete_gist                                              | CREATE INDEX autocomplete_gist ON public.hotels_hotel USING gist (name gist_trgm_ops)` and this query you've given here takes longer and doesn't return the right results: https://gist.github.com/mikob/f782768239b265d8631662de7b86d095

Comment: Well, you should edit the question and add the information there. Comments come and go. It would be nice to know all the index names and definitions; without that, I cannot interpret your snippet.

Comment: I've added the indices to the question.

Comment: Oops, I realized I made a small mistake in the operator: `<<->` instead of `<->>`. I fixed that in my answer.

Comment: Still not quite there for a typeahead, but much better performance wise. I'm now getting 2200ms queries (about 4x faster).

Comment: It should be using the index, right? I don't think you can get any faster, except by caching more data in memory.

Comment: How can I cache more data? Increase work_mem?

Comment: Get more RAM in the machine, use `pg_prewarm` on the index.

Comment: @jjanes I've turned it on and put the explain in edit 3

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've ran `select pg_prewarm('autocomplete_gist')` and even `select pg_prewarm('hotels_hotel')` but it made no difference. I've also tried raising work_mem from 4MB-> 32MB and shared_buffers from 128MB to 1GB and restarting. That also made no difference. Admittedly, I don't understand what is making the query slow.

Comment: That was helpful, because now we know that the I/O time is not the problem. The time is spent digging through lots of index pages. As Jeff said in his answer, GiST indexes are not very efficient for big tables. I am curious if the GIN index he recommends will do better.

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck with the GIN index rather than GiST.

GIN doesn't support KNN the way GiST does, so you instead you would have to apply the match operation with appropriate value of `pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold`, then sort the row which survive that.

```
SELECT name, word_similarity('trade center new york mariott', name) AS sml from hotels_hotel 
WHERE name %> 'trade center new york mariott' 
ORDER BY name <->> 'trade center new york mariott' 
LIMIT 5;
```

The planner doesn't make very clever distinctions between the cost of GIN and GiST indexes, so you might need to just drop the GiST index to get it to use the GIN.

Comment: I've set word_similarity_threshold to 0.3. Seems that will be a problem with AWS when I deploy. With the GiST index I get 1800ms on this query, without it I get 500ms - curiously. This query is better, but it seems to spend a lot of time on the bitmap heap scan, can that be improved? https://gist.github.com/mikob/5ce006bdbda617c4c9a0517ef8ca0e6b